# Не корректно работает captcha в ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему не корректно работает captcha. Captcha выводится при регистрации, если не вводить или не верно вводить, регистрация не проходит. Однако сообщения об ошибке или успешном введении значения не выводит! А именно должны быть сообщения: `TempData["Message"] = "Message: captcha is valid."` и `TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Error: captcha is not valid."`. Уверена, что допустила какую-то до боли глупую ошибку, но не могу найти!!

Как внедряла:

Установила с помощью `Nu GET CaptchaMVC`.

Контроллер:

```
//...
public class AccountController : Controller
    { // POST: /Account/Register


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, string empty )
    {

        if (this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha is not valid"))
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Message: captcha is valid.";
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, "question", "answer", true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                MigrateShoppingCart(model.UserName);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }

            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Error: captcha is not valid.";
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Модель:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100,ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

}
```

Вьюшка:

```
 @model MvcCosmeticsStore.Models.RegisterModel
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
<h2>
    Create a New Account</h2>
<p>
    Use the form below to create a new account.
</p>
<p>
    Passwords are required to be a minimum of @Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength
    characters in length.
</p>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.Captcha("Update", "Enter security code:", 5, "Required field", true)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```